# add product to cart using ajax?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, mini-cart

I have a bunch of product ids and an add to cart button. How when I click add to cart button, other list products are added to cart. I use javascript(ajax)t to handle the above requests. Hope the good help will get 1 good rating

Comment: Hi there , can you please let us know on more info about your requirements like in which page do you want to this request ? Thanks.

Comment: I have a form, user will enter the product id in it, then it saves the array of product ids in local storage. When the user clicks add to cart, the products with the id saved above will be added to the cart.